# What does the camera "module" add on top of the SONY IMX219?

Tags: camera, modules

New to electronics and Raspberry Pi, and I'm trying to understand exactly what a *camera module* is, versus just the camera/sensor itself.

Most hobbyist RPi projects advocate the use of the [RPi camera module](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera), because apparently it is an [SONY IMX219 camera sensor](https://www.sunfounder.com/camera-module-cam005.html) (which is what the RPi camera module uses under the hood) **plus** a bunch of other stuff the makes working with that camera a lot easier.

**I'm wondering what that "bunch of other stuff" is.**

So I ask: what other features, functions, bells & whistles does the RPi camera "module" add on top of the SONY IMX219 camera, for the average hobbyist?

Comment: My understanding (andI cold be wrong) the 'rest' is signal / impedance control circuitry.  The schematic is available https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/schematics/rpi_SCH_Camera2_2p1.pdf without it the interface does not work rather than the camera - the program drives the chip rather than the 'other stuff'.

Comment: WRT sensor vs module for hobbyists, the sensor alone would not simply be harder to use, it would be impossible, as in completely useless to you.  I'm not an expert, but I think turning a CMOS sensor into a useful camera module requires a professional industial setting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active-pixel_sensor  A crass analogy:  *I'm new to automotive goods, and I am wondering what that "bunch of other stuff" is I get with the "car module" that is "under the hood" an Acme V6 internal combustion engine.*  You can't drive an ICE down the street without a bunch of other stuff attached.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case though, @goldilocks. Take this [uCam-III camer sensor](https://4dsystems.com.au/mwdownloads/download/link/id/420/) for example. It's not a module. It just a sensor, isn't it (keep me honest!)? If so, by reading that data sheet there's nothing stopping me from writing my own driver for it, connecting its TX/RX/power/RESET/etc. pins to the RPi (taking voltage and other considerations into account of course) and having an app on the pi communicate with it. So if that's just a camera sensor (no module), what does the RPi camera module do for me?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup seriously? ... read the top of the title page of the document you linked

Comment: Hi @jsotola -- which one? The Rpi module link starts out with "_Learn how to connect the Raspberry Pi Camera Module to your Raspberry Pi and take pictures, record video, and apply image effects_". The Sunfounder link starts out with "_Get an eagle-like sharp and crystal clear vision_". Neither one of those explains to me what functionality the camera "module" adds on top of the camera itself.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup  your previous comment has a link to `uCam-III camer sensor` .... your post is not related to the RPi ... it is an about electronics ... the camera modules are used with other microcontrollers, besides the RPi

Comment: I feel like you're not really reading my comments. Above that post, Goldilocks had tried making the argument that - and I quote - "_the sensor alone would not simply be harder to use, it would be impossible_". So my response was, that there **are** camera sensors (just the sensors, not the modules), out there in the world, like the uCam-III, that I can connect to the RPi and use just fine. So his argument is not valid. I was making a point. My actual question up above _is_ about the RPi camera module and the underlying camera sensor it uses. So to be clear, my question is on topic.

Comment: But the pdf you linked (the uCam-III) *is not just a sensor*.  It's very clearly and explicitly a "serial **camera module**".  Look at the picture.  Again, I am not an expert, but I am certain that a CMOS sensor is not a camera lens, and so by definition, the sensor alone would not have a lens attached.  It also would not be on a breakout board with handy UART pins.  If you feel that is "just the sensor", then "a camera sensor" and "a camera module" are exactly the same thing (which makes it hard to understand how one could be only part of the other, of course).

Comment: Going back to why I am confident the sensor alone would be useless to most hobbyists, consider a couple of obvious points: 1) How are you going to mount a lens on it effectively?  Chances are, this is a very very finnicky relationship, 2) Look at the bottom of the uCam-II *camera module*, where you can see a square chip attached with dozens of tiny leads from all four sides.  That's either the sensor itself, or (more likely, I think) some kind of backpack microcontroller that, eg., is responsible for the UART.  Attaching that is beyond the capabilities of your average hobbyist...

Comment: ...simply because of the equipment required.  Someone who had it and could use it would really be a borderline professional and won't need to be asking questions like this.  I've been here almost eight years, most of that as a moderator, I read a high percentage of the questions (very often most of them), and I can't recall anyone ever discussing this.  If you want a more detailed, professional breakdown of the difference between *sensor* and *module* in this case, you might be better of trying this on the [Electrical Engineering SE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ...Just take care to explain while the camera module is sold for the Raspberry Pi, you are not asking about the Raspberry Pi but rather a generic question about the nomenclature of electronic components.  Otherwise they may shush you back here ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here @goldilocks (+1 on all) -- I realize now this was 100% a misunderstanding on my part. I really thought the uCam-III was _just_ a sensor. I'll leave this question open for another day or two in case anybody wants to provide an answer. Thanks again!